# 415 Unsupported Media Type during csv upload

Tags: java, angular, hibernate, jersey, response

I would like to upload csv file from client (Angular) and parse it on server (Java).
That's how my java enpoint looks like:

```
    @POST
    @Path( "/csv-objects" )
    @Consumes( MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA )
    public Response getCsvObjects(
        @FormDataParam( "file" ) InputStream aCsv,
        @FormDataParam( "file" ) FormDataContentDisposition aCsvDetails
    )
    {
        return Response.ok(csvImporter.getObjectsFromCsv( aCsv ) );
    }
```

Looks exactly like example reffered here [LINK](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.41/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataParam.html)

On the opposite client side:

```
  public importFromCsv(file: File): Observable<any> {
    const uploadedFile: FormData = new FormData();
    uploadedFile.append( 'file', file, file.name);
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.DEFAULT_ENDPOINT}/csv-objects`, uploadedFile);
}
```

I have also tried use Blob:

```
public importFromCsv(file: File): Observable<any> {
    const uploadedFile: FormData = new FormData();
        uploadedFile.append( 'file', new Blob([file], {type: 'text/csv'}) );
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.DEFAULT_ENDPOINT}/csv-objects`, uploadedFile);
}
```

or add headers `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` but there is no result - always getting **415 Unsupported Media Type**

[image: Paylload]

[image: Content]

What can be wrong?